# WSO2 Error with Registry UDDI

Tags: registry, wso2, uddi, wso2-esb

I´m using WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus 4.5.1.

I have installed Registry UDDI but when I start wso2server.bat it doesn´t start, the error is:

```
ERROR - JUDDIJAXWSDeployer Exception creating Axis Ser
vice : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PersistenceCapable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/openjpa/enhance/PersistenceCapable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(
DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(Clas
```

Any suggestion???

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did the right thing. The issue you are seeing is a known bug in this series of releases. We are working on a solution for this, and looking forward to fix this.

Please follow https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-1575.

Thanks,
Senaka.